# How to Retrieve true city name for selected district in edit view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

**Problem?**

I try more time to display wrong city for district selected

**Details**

I have District controller inside controller i have edit function

i retrieve selected country and city for District

in edit view.

but it display wrong city for district selected

for country it display correct country for select district

**code**

in District controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {

            Destrict D = db.Destricts.Find(id);
            ViewBag.CountryId = new SelectList(db.Countries.ToList(), "Id", "CountryName", D.City.Country.Id);
            return View(D);

        }
 public JsonResult getcitybyid(int x)
        {

            var data = db.Cities.Where(a => a.CountryId == x).ToList();
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
in view of edit

CountryName:@Html.DropDownList("CountryId","")
City:<select id="citylist"></select>

in jquery i fill country and city using

            $("#CountryId").change(function () {


                var id = $("#CountryId").val();
                 $("#citylist").empty();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/District/getcitybyid",
                    data: {x: id},
                    success:function(res)
                    {

                        $.each(res, function (i, e) {


                                $("#citylist").append("<option value='" + e.Id + "'>" + e.CityName + "<option>")



            $("#CountryId").change();
```

image show what i have

[get correct city for district](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw2mk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line

```
$("#citylist").append("<option value='" + e.Id + "'>" + e.CityName + "<option>")
```

The problem is , you did not close the `option` tag, Instead you opened a new one! That is the reason you are seeing double the options, half of them with empty display texts.

This should fix it (closing the option properly with `</option>`).

```
$("#citylist").append("<option value='" + e.Id + "'>" + e.CityName + "</option>");
```

For your edit screen, i suggest you create a view model like this

```
public class EditDistrictVm
{
  public List<SelectListItem> Countries { set;get;}
  public int SelectedCountry { set;get;}
  public List<SelectListItem> Cities { set;get;}
  public int SelectedCity { set;get;}
  public string Name { set;get;}
  public int Id { set;get;}
}
```

and in your EDIT action, load data to an object of this view model and send to view.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  var vm = new EditDistrictVm { Id=id};
  var d= db.Disticts.FirstOrDefault(id);
  vm.Name = d.Name;
  vm.Countries = db.Countries
                   .Select(f=>new SelectListItem { Value=f.Id.ToString(),
                                                   Text = f.CountryName}).ToList();
  //Now get cities for the country for this district
  vm.Cities =  db.Cities
                 .Where(t=>t.CountryId==d.City.CountrId)
                 .Select(f=>new SelectListItem { Value=f.Id.ToString(),
                                                 Text = f.CountryName}).ToList();

  //Set the selected options in dropdowns
  vm.SelectedCountryId=d.City.CountrId;
  vm.SelectedCityId = d.CityId;

  return View(vm);
}
```

Now make sure your edit view is strongly typed to this view model

```
@model EditDistrictVm
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(f=>f.Id)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(f=>f.Name)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(f=>f.SelectedCountry, Model.Countries)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(f=>f.SelectedCity, Model.Cities)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: sorry there are image wrong for problem the correct image for problem is http://www.mediafire.com/view/e3n80milbox9uk6/city_selected_wrong.jpg

Comment: So what is your problem now ? As long as you have correct data in the tables, it will give you the cities belongs to the selected country.

Comment: if you see this image above you will understand what i need

Comment: You need to set the selected option in your edit view. Use the DropDownListFor helper method

Comment: my problem i try more time to get city but it come wrong as image in comments

Comment: can you show me if possible how to do that by dropdownlistfor

Comment: thank you for help i will check then i will feedback in comments